# USB stick shows contents of a DIFFERENT stick

Tags: usb-drive, cache

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS 15 7590.  I've been having a really weird problem since I used this computer to create a bootable USB Stick so I could install Xubuntu 20.04 on a different computer.  I used this command to create the bootable USB stick:

```
$ sudo dd bs=4M if=xubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sda status=progress oflag=sync
```

Notice that I used `/dev/sda`, not `/dev/sda1`.  (And no, I didn't overwrite my system disk; the system disk is `/dev/nvme0n1`.)

The install stick worked great, and I successfully installed Xubuntu 20.04 on the other computer.  **But now, when I insert *any* USB stick into my Xubuntu 18.04 Dell computer, it appears to be the install stick that I created!**  It auto-mounts as an ISO filesystem, and I can even read the files, even though they definitely aren't on the USB stick that I put in.  It doesn't matter what size the USB stick is or what port I insert it into -- they all appear the same.

It seems like the stick's partition table and ISO filesystem is cached (maybe possible because this computer has 32GB RAM), and Linux is always re-using that same cache for every USB stick, regardless of the stick's serial number, label, or whatever else sticks use as identity.

Here is the `lsblk` of a different 4GB USB Stick (*not* the Xubuntu 20.04 install stick!):

```
$ sudo lsblk -O /dev/sda
NAME KNAME MAJ:MIN FSTYPE MOUNTPOINT LABEL UUID                                 PARTTYPE PARTLABEL PARTUUID PARTFLAGS  RA RO RM HOTPLUG MODEL SERIAL  SIZE STATE OWNER GROUP MODE       ALIGNMENT MIN-IO OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED RQ-SIZE TYPE DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO WSAME WWN RAND PKNAME HCTL       TRAN SUBSYSTEMS  REV VENDOR ZONED
sda  sda     8:0                                                                                                      128  0  1       1 HS US         3.7G runni root  disk  brw-rw----         0   1024      0    1024    1024    1 mq-deadline
│                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                2 disk        0        0B       0B         0    0B        1        3:0:0:0    usb  block:scsi:usb:pci
│                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              2.00 ACTION none
└─sda1
     sda1    8:1   iso966            Xubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64
                                           2020-04-23-07-50-17-00                                                     128  0  1       1               3.7G       root  root  -rw-r--r--         0   1024      0    1024    1024    1 mq-deadline
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 2 part        0        0B       0B         0    0B        1 sda                    block:scsi:usb:pci
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           none
```

Here's a different 32GB stick:

```
$ sudo lsblk -O /dev/sda
NAME KNAME MAJ:MIN FSTYPE MOUNTPOINT LABEL UUID                                 PARTTYPE PARTLABEL PARTUUID PARTFLAGS  RA RO RM HOTPLUG MODEL SERIAL  SIZE STATE OWNER GROUP MODE       ALIGNMENT MIN-IO OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED RQ-SIZE TYPE DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO WSAME WWN RAND PKNAME HCTL       TRAN SUBSYSTEMS  REV VENDOR ZONED
sda  sda     8:0                                                                                                      128  0  1       1 Patri 07014B 28.9G runni root  disk  brw-rw----         0    512      0     512     512    1 mq-deadline
│                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                2 disk        0        0B       0B         0    0B        1        3:0:0:0    usb  block:scsi:usb:pci
│                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              PMAP        none
└─sda1
     sda1    8:1   iso966            Xubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64
                                           2020-04-23-07-50-17-00                                                     128  0  1       1              28.9G       root  root  -rw-r--r--         0    512      0     512     512    1 mq-deadline
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 2 part        0        0B       0B         0    0B        1 sda                    block:scsi:usb:pci
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           none
```

As you can see, they both appear to have the "Xubuntu 20.04" label, even though they really don't.

Do you guys have any ideas?  Thanks.

**Different problem, but probably related:** https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/7883827?hl=en

Comment: `/dev/sda` is typically the local (internal) disk. Are you sure you've not overwritten your system?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  On my computer, the system disk is `/dev/nvme0n1`.

Comment: Does `mount | grep sda` return anything?

Comment: When I first insert a USB stick, the system auto-mounts the cached ISO filesystem:  `/dev/sda1 on /media/likebike/Xubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64 type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmode=500,fmode=400,uhelper=udisks2)`   ...But then I manually un-mount it.

Comment: That's very strange. Certainly not what I'd expect

Comment: Yep, me too.  :)

Comment: what does `lsblk` give with and without the usb plugged?

Comment: With no stick plugged in, `lsblk` only shows my system disk ('nvme0n1').  With the stick plugged in, it also shows the 'sda' lines that I posted in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you've actually `dd`'ed into /dev/sda when the device /dev/sda wasn't recognised by the system for some reason, like you'd forgot to put it in, or the connection went funny for a minute, or something like that, so `/dev/sda` is now an actual file stored in /dev, instead of a special device file populated by the system?

Does `ls -lga /dev/sd*` still show sda even when the USB drives have been removed? Or is it gone like you'd expect until one's plugged in. Also do multiple extra /dev/sd* devices pop up when you plug one in? Could it be that it's assigning new drives to sdb, sdc etc as expected, but still mounting that /dev/sda image file only when another hardware drive is detected? A way to tell between regular and device files is whether the owner shows "disk" or "root"

!! - pretty much the entire next paragraph has potential for data loss, so be double-sure there's nothing on the USB that you want, double-check root, take backups etc!!

If the /dev/sda seems to exist as a file on its own regardless of whether there's a USB in, and you're certain it's not root or another file system with important stuff on, just try `rm /dev/sda`ing it. If it only exists when there's a USB in, and there is no other sdb/sdc/sd[etc] being made when one's inserted, something may have gone wrong on the device's partition table. You can create a new one using fdisk(mbr)/gdisk(gpt)/gparted(graphical/both) but that will cause data loss.

A last path of investigation, how does `ls /dev/disk/by-id/` change when you add/remove usb drives in the current state?

Comment: WOW!  You are a GENIUS!  You were right -- there was a `/dev/sda1` regular file.  I deleted it, and now everything works as expected.  I'm really amazed you were able to figure that out.